# How to query across databases in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two different SQL Azure databases.  However, they are on the same instance.  My question is, how can I query a table in database 2 from database 1.  I am aware of the functionality of external tables, however performance is bad here and I am not sure the cost implications of using external tables.  I am wondering if there is a simpier way to do this, especially if the 2 databases are on the same instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge the only way to do this on Azure SQL Database is using elastic queries, but you need to make sure parameterized operations are pushed to remote databases so they can be evaluated remotely. You need to avoid large row sets have to be unnecessarily brought local to evaluate these operations. Learn how to push parameterized operations on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) article.

Examine query plans and monitor DTU performance on all databases involved. Make sure indexes exist for remote queries to execute faster.

Comment: The new Managed Instance supports _regular_ cross-database queries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron Are you willing to try a Managed Instance instead?

Comment: I am willing however, the setup seems kinda complicated.  We will need to do this for multiple customers.  For right now though it seems like our only option.  Thank you!